# How do you find out where a property is used in a pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Hi I got a really messy pom with lots of properties defined. The true use for these properties are lost overtime. How do you find out which plug-in reads which property?

Obviously I am not expecting answers telling me to reference each readme of the plug-ins. I am expecting a command line argument to list that for me

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would render `effective-pom` and `grep` for property

**For example**

```
mvn help:effective-pom | grep '{property-key}' -A 20 -B 20
```

Comment: Thanks. But I fail to see how this is useful.

Comment: You search the effective pom for the properties. If they are really used anywhere (by the literal search for {property-key}).

Comment: My question is about finding out where the properties are used and are used by which plug-in. The effective pom shows the properties that are used but not where they are used.

Comment: No you can't check that, what is some class is reading it as System property how would you scan all the classes to check that, there is no existing support for that